# WordPress ajax-admin.php returns status 200 (Success) with response text 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried several solutions that I found on Google/Stack Overflow like adding `die()` at the end of the function, `echo true` etc., but none of them worked. The function should be simple. Don't know what the problem is. So here are the details:

**My HTML FORM**

```
<form id="formRangeYStand">
    <div class="range" id="range_y_stand">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="5" steps="1" value="1" id="range_y_stand_input" name="range_y_stand_input">
    </div>
    <ul class="range-labels" id="range_y_stand_label" style="text-align: left;">
        <li class="active selected"><span></span></li>
        <li style="text-align: center; margin-left: -20px;"><span>Learning</span></li>
        <li><span>Can do</span></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px;"><span>Can do well</span></li>
        <li style="margin-left: -4px; text-align: right;"><span>Mastered</span></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**My Javascript code**

```
Query("#formRangeYStand").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        var form = jQuery("#formRangeYStand").serialize();
        var formData = new FormData;
        formData.append('action', 'testiram');
        formData.append('testiram', form);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: link,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

**My PHP Code (functions.php)**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_testiram', 'testiram');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testiram', 'testiram');


function testiram() {
     echo true;
    wp_die();
}
```

Result:

[image: picture result]

I know this is a common question but I still don't understand why my code still returns zero in success response and I tried almost everything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP predefine functions.

> - [wp_send_json_success()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/)
> - [wp_send_json_error()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/)
> - [wp_send_json()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_testiram', 'testiram');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testiram', 'testiram');
function testiram() {
    wp_send_json_success();
}
```

Pass `dataType : "json",`

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: link,
    dataType : "json",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried, the same situation. I'm getting 0 as a result.